# How Playframework 1.x static method works in a thread safe way

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Might be a silly question, but I'm noob learning Play framework 1.2.5.
I've noticed that the controller actions are all static methods and I assume each request will be processed in a separate thread. If that's the case, how Play framework ensures these static controller methods are thread safe? I think, as long as we are not sharing anything between controller methods then we are good (?), please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we're quite good. As you know HTTP is **stateless**, so nothing will be shared between requests. Play uses `ThreadLocal`s while processiong the request. Each request has it's own thread so you have full control of the current request - response life cycle.

If you want to share data between controllers, you have `session` object however it's quite small and accepts only `String`s. For other data types or different implementations of sharing, you should use a `Cache` implementation. For further information see [session](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/controllers#session) and [cache](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/cache) documentations.

Good luck!